# Two way binding ngStyle

Tags: javascript, angular

Im trying to make `ngStyle` change its `left` field value whenever i change something to my `range value`.

i was inspired by how its done on: https://codepen.io/mayuMPH/pen/ZjxGEY
but im not finding a way to do this in angular6-7.

only when the document is loaded the left `ngStyle` value will change. but i dont get it to work when i drag the range. how can i achieve the `rs-bullet` to follow the value?

html code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="range-slider">
    <span id="rs-bullet" [ngStyle]="{'left':RangePos}"   (change)="changeZoom()" class="rs-label" >{{ rangeValue }}</span>
    <input id="rs-range-line" [(ngModel)]="rangeValue" class="rs-range" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100">

  </div>

  <div class="box-minmax">
    <span>0</span><span>200</span>
  </div>



</div>
```

component:

```
  rangeValue = 0;
  RangePos = ((40 / 1000) * 578) + 'px';

  ngOnInit() {






  }

  changeZoom() {
    this.RangePos = ((this.rangeValue / 1000) * 578) + 'px';
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `change` on `span` because there is no such event on it. Actually, you don't even need it, because `ngModel` should handle all the changes.

So, to make your example working you should just change

```
changeZoom() {
    return ((this.rangeValue / 1000) * 578) + 'px';
}
```

and

```
<span id="rs-bullet" [ngStyle]="{'left': changeZoom()}" 
      class="rs-label" >{{ rangeValue }}
</span>
```

Also divider 1000 in your example is incorrect because you input range max value is 100.

Here you can see your example, working in Angular: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-66fr5v.

Be sure, that you've added `FormsModule` to the application module. Otherwise `ngModel` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set a function to bind Style like this?

```
<span id="rs-bullet" [ngStyle]="setRangePosStyles(RangePos)" (change)="changeZoom()" class="rs-label" >{{ rangeValue }}</span>
```

component:

```
setRangePosStyles(RangePos){
        return {'left':RangePos};
    }
```